# How to clone an Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image in UWP?

Tags: c#, image, clone, uwp

I want to clone an image into another variable in UWP, It seems that we don't have cloning for `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image` in UWP.

Why we don't have this method in UWP and how I can make a copy of Image?

Comment: Why would you clone an Image control, when you could simply have to Image controls with the same `Source` property value?

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I want, I need all of the properties of a specific image to be copied, for example, Width, Height, Position, Margin, ...

Comment: Because, I need them for my animation effect.

Comment: As you have already realized that there is no clone method, what keeps you from creating a new Image and set the values of all *relevant* properties to those of the source Image? For "why we don't have this method" you would have to ask Microsoft.